# How to submit an unnamed form on another page in JavaScript {Chrome Console}

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've been trying to submit a form on another page that isn't named. I'm using the Chrome Console.

I have it to where it gets to the page, checks to make sure item exists, but I don't know how to automatically buy it (i.e. submit the unnamed form on the page)

Here is my JS that is being submitted in the console:

```
var nextID = "48"; // set to id after last item
var link = "/Store/Item.php?ID=";

var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type.
jQuery.noConflict();


function snipe() {
setInterval(function(){ 
        console.log("Checking if ID is valid for " + nextID); 
       $.post( link + nextID, function(data) {
        match = data.match(/<b>([^<]*)<\/b>/);
            if (!(match[1] == "This item does not exist.")) {
                // Here is where we need to submit the forum on that page.
                console.log("Bought item with id of " + nextID);
            } 
        });
    }, 3000);
}

snipe();
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to use a script on one page to invoke an event on a different page?

Comment: Exactly. I want to invoke the form submit.